# How to link crawled products to other products(record linkage)

Tags: database, algorithm, data-science

I made a web scrapper which goes to many predefined online stores and collects products data then save them in a structured way in my database. something like this:

```
{
   title: "Samsung Galaxy S20 5G",
   price: 1250,
   description: "some text here",
   brand: "Samsung"
   specification: [
      ram: 12GB,
      Capacity: 128GB
   ]
   sellerId: 2,
   category: "smartphones"
   internalProductId: null
}
```

I want to use this data to make a price comparison website.
something like this [website](https://www.pricerunner.com/pl/1-3200339453/Mobile-Phones/Apple-iPhone-13-128GB-Compare-Prices)

my problem is I don't know how to map/connect/match these collected products to my original product in my website. so their seller and price is shown under that original product. (Here that `internalProductId` is id of original product in my website.)

for example I have this product in my website:

Samsung A71 128GB/8Gb  ‍‍‍‍ ‍‍‍ ‍‍ id: 1

when I crawled several online store I want to use a technology/algorithm to analyze collected products, recognize similar  products that match to my products and give them appropriate `internalProductId`.

I'm interested to any accurate solution any  matching algorithm any technology any suggestion. (I'm not interested to machine learning solutions)

Comment: It's a pretty hard problem. My not very good first idea would be to form a digest from selected fields, washing out case, whitespace, etc., and save it with each record.  The hope is that two products that are near each other in reality have digests that near each other in levenshtien distance.

Comment: @danh I've developed a service, in which I break products title into words then I find Levenshtien distance between two titles and save it to an array. the original product has some keywords so I compare it with title of collected product and push the result to previous array again, then I include brand, category and other specifications scores' to that array, and finally I analyze the array numbers . yet it's not accurate :((